# How to access community id in facebook workplace?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I am trying to access workplace data using Facebook Workplace API. I am the System Administrator for the workplace. Still I dont get the CommunityId in the Custom Integrations page.

Has anyone come across this same situation? Any suggestions would be great !!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find your Community ID by making a Graph API GET call to graph.facebook.com/community with a custom integration access token (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/reference/community)